# How to merge two GitHub project boards?

Tags: github

I want to move the entire project board of a GitHub repository to another. Is there any way that can be done without manually copying each and every card.

Project board is a feature on GitHub to organize and prioritize work. [More](https://help.github.com/articles/about-project-boards/)

Thank you.

EDIT:

When I contacted GitHub Support, I got the following response.

> There isn't currently a way to merge a Project on GitHub, but I can
>   definitely see how that would be useful. I can't make any promises but
>   I'll let the team know you'd like to see us add this feature in the
>   future.

Comment: No. You may have some luck with contacting someone at GitHub to possibly give you a hand with that: https://github.com/contact

Comment: I was unfamiliar with this feature of GitHub until reading your question. It might help to clarify by providing links to relevant GitHub docs.

Comment: This has nothing to do with git. You should contact [GitHub support](https://github.com/contact) about this.

Comment: I was thinking maybe I am missing something very obvious, hence I was hesitating to reach out to GitHub support. I will contact them. Thank you.  @j-titus

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thank you for the comment. I will do.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have added a link to a GitHub doc. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I have been looking if a GitHub repo has any hidden branches or commits for Project Boards [like there are for pull requests](https://gist.github.com/piscisaureus/3342247). However, no luck.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. I have messaged GitHub support. Will update the question if I get a response. @Code-Apprentice

Comment: You may want to check out waffle.io <-- i realise this isn't native, but it does appear to integrate quite well, I'm going to be trying it out and reporting back